# Use grepl to name a variabele

Tags: r, grepl

I have the following dataframe

```
amount <- c(10,12,14)
description <- c("bankafschrift", "ABN", "albert heijn") 
df <- data.frame(description, amount)


head(df)
description amount
1 bankafschrift     10
2           ABN     12
3  albert heijn     14
```

Now, I want to do a little textmining where I appoint a post to rows based on words in their description. So a description containing: "bankafschrift" I want to declare as "Bank". I know how to get a true/false value  like this:

```
 df$post <- grepl('A
```

Which gives me:

```
   description amount  post 
1 bankafschrift     10 FALSE       
2           ABN     12  TRUE         
3  albert heijn     14 FALSE
```

But I want the post to say "groceries" in case the grepl statement is true. Any suggestions on how to this?

And on top this:

If I want to more items for determining the post how would I use a list?

If do this:

```
 bank_items <- c("Bank", "ABN")
 f$post <- grepl(bank_items,df$description)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Warning message:
In grepl(bank_items, df$description) :
argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the right way to go for this problem? Maybe a lookup-table might be easier if you have many different descriptions and/or categorizations.

Answer (score 1):

We can `paste` the 'bank_items' together and use that as `pattern` in `grepl`.

```
 i1 <- grepl(paste(bank_items, collapse='|'), df$description)
 ifelse(i1, 'Bank cost', 'Not Bank cost')
```

Comment: sweet thanks. And you also know how to solve my first problem?

Comment: @MarcvanderPeet  I am sorry, what is the first problem.

Comment: I do not want i to say true or false but in case the grepl(paste(bank_items, collapse='|'), df$description) is true I want df$post to be "Bank cost"

Comment: @MarcvanderPeet  Updated the post.